# Does TDE not protect against disk theft?

Tags: encryption, databases, sql-server, key

I read the following on Microsoft's site. Can someone please clarify -

> **"With TDE, is the data stored in my data, log, and backup files protected from a disk theft?"**
>
> Yes, but only if the files are stored on a separate disk separate from
>   the OS image, and if the attacker does not steal the disk containing
>   the OS image as well. TDE only aims to protect the database files,
>   including data, logs, backups, snapshots, and database copies, but not
>   the entire disk. If the OS image and data files are located on the
>   same disk, an attacker can restore and compromise the data. A
>   recommended best practice is to store the OS image and database files
>   on separate disks for additional security.

My question is around the OS image part - "***If the OS image and data files are located on the same disk, an attacker can restore and compromise the data.***"

Why would this be the case? If the TDE keys are stored in an external vault, how does stealing OS image and Data Files allow an attacker to compromise data?